# Как обернуть все приложение в Fabric?

Tags: android

Fabric криво работает опять.

Ошибка типо NullPointer а на сервер ничего не приходит.

Как мне все приложение все Acitvity обернуть в Crashlictys.loge? в oncreate писать try catch после в onresume, destroy короче во все функции каждого класса что ли?

Comment: Ну что скажите. Есть предложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если есть возможность принудительно отправлять сообщения об ошибках, то можно попробовать вот так реагировать на все ошибки и вручную сообщение отправлять.

Это надо в onCreate активити прописать:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler()
{
    Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler oldHandler=Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)
    {
        Log.e(LOG, "Ошибка поймана");
        //здесь делаем то, что хотели сделать в onPause, но не успели, т.к. упали. 

        //Если используем какую-либо либу, обрабатывающую ошибки
        //ACRA, например, то надо вызвать дальнейшую обработку ошибки 
        //дефолтным обработчиком

        //Также это надо вызвать чтобы падение по ошибке со стандартным диалогом не завершилось ANR вместо него.
        if(oldHandler!=null)
        {
            oldHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        }
    }
});
```